# Proguarding Google Play Services 7.+ results in com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced method 'boolean isAttachedToWindow()'

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, android-proguard

I have an app that is close to the 65K method count limit. I'm currently using Proguard without obfuscation

```
# This is a configuration (rules) file for ProGuard.
-dontobfuscate
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

# Dex does not like code run through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps
# (and performs some of these optimizations on its own).
-dontpreverify
-dontoptimize
-verbose

# Only run ProGuard shrinking against Google Play Services (package = com.google.android.gms.*)
-keep class !com.google.** (also tried !com.google.android.** / !com.google.android.gms.**)
-dontwarn !com.google.** (also tried !com.google.android.** / !com.google.android.gms.**)
```

to strip out unused methods in its dependencies:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0'
```

However, $ ./gradlew assemble gives the following error:

```
:proguardGoogleDebug
Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced method 'boolean isAttachedToWindow()' in program class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig
Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
         You may need to recompile the code.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
:proguardGoogleDebug FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Has anyone troubleshooted this issue before? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are compileSDK is >= 19. View#isAttachedToWindow was added in 19.